# AndroidのHomeButtonをクリックできるようにしたい。

Tags: android

アクティビティを
MainActivity
Test
と2つ作り、Testアクティビティの
ActionBarにHomeButtonをつけて、それをクリックしたら
MainActivityに戻れるようにしたいのです。

まず、
プリセットに家のアイコンがなかったので、家のgif画像を作って、
左のツリーのdrawableを右クリックして
New→Image Assetをクリックして
Icon TypeはAction Bar and Tab Icon
Nameはic_home
Asset TypeはImageを選択してgif画像を選択しました。
すると、drawableのところにic_home.pngというフォルダができて、
解像度ごとに4つのpng画像ができました。

それから、
Test.javaに
次のように記述しました。

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

これでHomeButtonは表示されるのですが、
それをクリックしても、波紋が出ずに何も反応がないのです。
HomeButtonはクリックできない仕様なのでしょうか。

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

の下に

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

と記入すると、矢印(←)のアイコンが出て、
それをクリックすると波紋が出てクリックの反応があり、
MainActivityに戻ることができます。

この矢印のアイコンを家のアイコンに変えられれば完璧なのですが。
つまり、
`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled`で表示した家のアイコンがクリックできるようにするか、
`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`で表示した矢印を家のアイコンに変えられるか、
どちらかができればいいのですが。

Android Studioのバージョンは3.0.1で、
minimum SDKはAndroid 4.0.3で作っています。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: すいません、自己解決しました。
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_home);
を追加すると矢印が家のアイコンになりました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合も回答として投稿ください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1747/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに投稿してしまい、大変失礼いたしました。
自己解決しました。 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
の下に
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_home);
を追加すると
矢印が家のアイコンになりました。